# Inserting multiple parameters into single field in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like some help with saving multiple params in single field in mysql.

[image]I have a field called params in mysql table. In that field I would like to save multiple parms for example

```
{"row_no":1, "pic_no":3}, {"row_no":2, "pic_no":2}, {"row_no":3, "pic":3}.
```

If you look into attached image, when user click any image, i would like to save the table row number of that image and also the image number.

I have done ajax which sends the row and pic number.

I need help with inserting the data in database.

I need update else insert statement.

```
Update param if row_no already exist 
else 
insert {"row_no":(clicked image row), "pic_no":clicked image no}
```

I will need to add multiple {"row_no":,    "pic_no":} in param field

Thank you in advance

Comment: No good idea. You should normalize your table and store These Information in a one to many relationship

Comment: This information will be stored just for temporary. Once all the images will be clicked the parameter will be deleted

Comment: There is no need to normalize information, you can use a NoSql approach storing the information in JSON fields

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON column type.

> The JSON data type provides these advantages over storing JSON-format strings in a string column:
>
> Automatic validation of JSON documents stored in JSON columns. Invalid documents produce an error.
>
> Optimized storage format. JSON documents stored in JSON columns are converted to an internal format that permits quick read access to document elements. When the server later must read a JSON value stored in this binary format, the value need not be parsed from a text representation. The binary format is structured to enable the server to look up subobjects or nested values directly by key or array index without reading all values before or after them in the document.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html